# Commands from bat file is missing

Tags: command, pre-build-event

I am having a tough time running a set of prebuild tasks. I am getting an error indicating that the commands are not found. I am not sure where to start. The project contains a bat file with the following commands

taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq BrowserStackLocal.exe"

taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq IEDriverServer.exe"

taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq chromedriver.exe"

taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq geckodriver.exe"

copy "$(SolutionDir)externals\BrowserStackLocal.exe" "$(ProjectDir)bin\debug\BrowserStackLocal.exe"

build output.

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: USCBTest.Tools.TaskKill, Configuration: chrome Any CPU ------
1>EXEC : error : Not found
1>  
1>EXEC : error : Not found
1>  
1>EXEC : error : Not found
1>  
1>EXEC : error : Not found
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1372,5): error MSB3073: The command "
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1372,5): error MSB3073: taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq BrowserStackLocal.exe"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1372,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1372,5): error MSB3073: taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq IEDriverServer.exe"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1372,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1372,5): error MSB3073: taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq chromedriver.exe"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1372,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1372,5): error MSB3073: taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq geckodriver.exe"" exited with code 1.
2>------ Build started: Project: USCBTest.Core, Configuration: chrome Any CPU ------
3>------ Build started: Project: USCBTest.Data, Configuration: chrome Any CPU ------
4>------ Build started: Project: USCBTest.Runner, Configuration: chrome Any CPU ------
4>  SpecFlowFeatureFiles: 
4>  SpecFlowGeneratedFiles: 
3>  USCBTest.Data -> C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Data\bin\chrome\USCBTest.Data.dll
2>  USCBTest.Core -> C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Core\bin\chrome\USCBTest.Core.dll
5>------ Build started: Project: USCBTest.Pages, Configuration: chrome Any CPU ------
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\WOMBAT\MYFAction.cs(17,13,17,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\WOMBAT\TeamAssignment.cs(17,13,17,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\WOMBAT\WorkloadReallocator.cs(18,13,18,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\Itrust.cs(20,13,20,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\WOMBAT\AssignAction.cs(17,13,17,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\WOMBAT\PotentialAction.cs(12,13,12,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\WOMBAT\Reports.cs(12,13,12,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\WOMBAT\DP2Action.cs(17,13,17,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\WOMBAT\WombatHome.cs(17,13,17,24): warning CS0618: 'PageFactory' is obsolete: 'The PageFactory implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
5>  USCBTest.Pages -> C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Pages\bin\chrome\USCBTest.Pages.dll
4>  USCBTest.Runner -> C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.Runner\bin\chrome\USCBTest.Runner.exe
6>------ Build started: Project: USCBTest.TestCases, Configuration: chrome Any CPU ------
6>  SpecFlowFeatureFiles: Features\WOMBAT\WOMBAT SFTP.feature
6>  SpecFlowGeneratedFiles: Features\WOMBAT\WOMBAT SFTP.feature.cs
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(83,54,83,76): warning CS0618: 'FeatureContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the FeatureContext via Context Injection - https://go.specflow.org/Migrate-FeatureContext-Current'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(94,17,94,40): warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://go.specflow.org/Migrate-ScenarioContext-Current'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(113,22,113,45): warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://go.specflow.org/Migrate-ScenarioContext-Current'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(117,96,117,119): warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://go.specflow.org/Migrate-ScenarioContext-Current'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(121,95,121,118): warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://go.specflow.org/Migrate-ScenarioContext-Current'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(125,95,125,118): warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://go.specflow.org/Migrate-ScenarioContext-Current'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(129,94,129,117): warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://go.specflow.org/Migrate-ScenarioContext-Current'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(142,57,142,80): warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://go.specflow.org/Migrate-ScenarioContext-Current'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(162,13,162,32): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(162,50,162,69): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(162,46,162,71): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.DesiredCapabilities()' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(164,13,164,67): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(165,13,165,67): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(167,13,167,83): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(168,13,168,81): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(173,21,173,71): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(174,21,174,68): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(175,21,175,76): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(178,21,178,70): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(179,21,179,64): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(180,21,180,67): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(185,13,185,82): warning CS0618: 'DesiredCapabilities.SetCapability(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(194,48,194,53): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(196,49,196,54): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(198,48,198,53): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\Hooks.cs(206,46,206,51): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\WOMBAT\WOMBATSFTP.cs(1404,136,1404,137): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\WOMBAT\WOMBATSFTP.cs(2510,21,2510,39): warning CS0618: 'ExpectedConditions' is obsolete: 'The ExpectedConditions implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\WOMBAT\WOMBATSFTP.cs(3227,21,3227,39): warning CS0618: 'ExpectedConditions' is obsolete: 'The ExpectedConditions implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\WOMBAT\WOMBATSFTP.cs(35,24,35,41): warning CS0649: Field 'WOMBATSFTP.currentSpecialist' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\WOMBAT\WOMBATSFTP.cs(36,24,36,37): warning CS0649: Field 'WOMBATSFTP.newSpecialist' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\WOMBAT\WOMBATSFTP.cs(25,48,25,69): warning CS0169: The field 'WOMBATSFTP._specFlowOutputHelper' is never used
6>C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\Steps\WOMBAT\WOMBATSFTP.cs(37,24,37,35): warning CS0414: The field 'WOMBATSFTP.grantNumber' is assigned but its value is never used
6>  USCBTest.TestCases -> C:\WOMBATLATEST\QA-Automation\USCBTest.TestCases\bin\chrome\USCBTest.TestCases.dll
========== Build: 5 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried the commands individually from the command prompt. I tried a lot of other steps that are totally irrelevant such as making sure the target framework are identical on all the projects. I updated VS, I suspect there is an exe file missing but I just don't know for sure.